# Infinite closed subset of $[0, 1]$ that does not have any subset of the form $[a, b]$ for $a< b$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What is an infinite closed subset of $[0, 1]$ that does not have any subset of the form $[a, b]$ for $a< b$?

Comment: Do you want examples, or do you want to know the terminology for such a set?

Comment: What is an "infinite closed" set?

Comment: {0} U {1/n}$$$$

Answer (score 7):

$\{ \frac{i}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} ^*\}\cup\{0\}$

Answer (score 6):

For example the Cantor set, obtained removing the middle third of $[0,1]$, then the middle thirds of the two intervals that remain, and so on. The Cantor set is the limit of this procedure and being a closed set at each step, it is also a closed set at the end, since it will be an intersection of closed sets.

Comment: Its a "perfect" answer.

Comment: A nowhere dense set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set